# Airline CO2 emissions

Tags: life-cycle-analysis

There are 50,000 aircraft in the air or idling all the time. An airliner consumes 5 tons (or whatever) per hour of fuel. So 3 billion tons per year of fuel. So one ton of fuel is actually 3 tons of CO<sub>2</sub>, so 10 billion total.

American CO<sub>2</sub> emissions are 10 billion tons, according to [this page](https://www.epa.gov/ghgemissions/inventory-us-greenhouse-gas-emissions-and-sinks). So how is it mathematically possible the airline industry produces more CO<sub>2</sub> than the entire country combined?

Comment: Well, if you said "airline(r)", the 50K figure is way too much. It's too much even if you include small aircraft (which consume 1-2 orders of magnitude less). The usual estimate is 7-9 thousand aircraft in the air (for which 5 t/h is a reasonable order-of-magnitude average). So here you are ~order of magnitude off, and the rest is plausible (again within the order): _worldwide_ industry produces ~10% of a country's emission. If you need an exact tally, I'm sure somebody already did it.

Comment: An idling aircraft uses far less fuel than one that's cruising, which in turn uses far less fuel than one that's taking off.  You can't just say "an airplane uses *x* tons of fuel per hour".

Comment: The linked article mentions how in 2021 the total of American greenhouse emissions was a little above 6 billion metric ("*6,340.2 million*") tons.

Answer (score 1):

> So how is it mathematically possible the airline industry produces more co2 than the entire country combined?

The airline industry is worldwide.  Of course, a worldwide industry can and does produce more CO₂ emissions than the total emissions from any particular country.

Answer (score 1):

You've presented a lot of numbers without any sources.  If instead of following your calculation based on unreferenced values, we simply search for CO2 emissions by the aviation sector, we [find](https://www.iea.org/energy-system/transport/aviation#) that 2022 worldwide CO2 emissions totaled 800 Mtons, per the International Energy Agency.  This is described as 80% of pre-pandemic values, so 1 Gton seems to be a reasonable value to use.

Thus, your calculation is off by an order of magnitude.